# Looking for two position right-angle vertically stacked wire-to-board connectors

Tags: pcb, connector, power-connector

Here's an approximate side view of the connector I'm looking for:
[image: side angle rendition of connector]
the leads extend out from the back, then drop at a right angle into the PCB.

I know they exist, because I have an old board with them in it, but it is locked in a lab indefinitely, so I can't look for a part number. I've tried a lot of searching, mostly with combinations of the classifiers two-position, right-angle, vertically stacked, wire-to-board, through-hole, etc.
They are fairly large connectors and should be rated for high amperage. I think 40A or more, but they might be rated for smaller.

Comment: DIN41612 at a guess but could literally be any one of thousands that look pretty similar but are all subtly different.

Comment: Maybe try a search for 'right angle dual female header' on Mouser or Digikey, and then filter the table for higher amperage connectors? Good luck!

Comment: There are jillions of such connectors to choose from, depending on things like voltage, current, impedance, compliance spacing, overall size, number of circuits, etc.  Plus, there are non-standard options such as right-angle D-sub parts.  What are you trying to connect?

Comment: @AnalogKid I'm trying to connect various motors/controllers to a power distribution board for a robot. The robot has pretty strict size limitations, so I'm trying to reduce the footprint of the PDB by using these connectors. The highest current draw through one of these should be about 30A. I'm not looking for a specific connector, just one that would work with the smallest footprint.

Comment: One of the options in a "Combo-D" connector, which is a standard D-sub shell with different pins.  One option is a 40 A contact.  Cannon, Positronic, etc.  https://www.connectpositronic.com/series/cbd/

Comment: Look into Molex mini fit Senior. They handle up to 50A and have horizontal mounting.https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family/minifit_sr

Comment: Thank you all. The Connector I was looking for was from the Molex mega-fit family. It turns out that they are only rated for 23A. I'm now looking at using Anderson powerpole PP15/45 products for higher currents.